# How to update the data of slickgrid on row change?

Tags: row, slickgrid

I want to update the slickgrid on everyrowchange in the sense after making the changes in entire row i want event to fire update.

Can anybody suggest please?

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid has no concept of editing a row, only editing individual cells. If the user edits several cells in a row, how would you decide when the edit to the whole row is complete?

If you consider the row complete when the last column is edited, you can set an event handler on cell edit for the last column and react appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array of "Dirty Row IDs".
Then when the *selected row* changes, loop through your array of *Dirty Row IDs* and do your thing.